# TSQL Select basic hierarchical data from JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

This is a rediculously simple question, but I cannot find a single working example anywhere.  MSDN hints it is possible ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server)), but misses the actual example, and Google presents a myriad of examples outputting JSON *from* TSQL, whereas I need the reverse.

Taking a most basic JSON structure:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{
    "Id":       1,
    "name":     "John",
    "skills": [
        {"title":   "Azure" },
        {"title":   "VB" },
        {"title":   "JavaScript" }]
}, {
    "Id":       2,
    "name":     "Jane",
     "skills": [
        {"title":   "Azure" },
        {"title":   "SQL" },
        {"title":   "C#" }]
}]';
```

I figured how to get the highest-level values, such as `Id` and `name`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
    ID int '$.Id',
    name nvarchar(50) '$.name'
    );
```

What I'd like is to output **PersonId**, and the respective **skill title**s for each, e.g.

```
PersonId     SkillTitle
-----------------------
1            Azure
1            VB
1            JavaScript
2            Azure
2            SQL
2            C#
```

Google only provides me with the reverse logic.  My badly-broken attempt based on what I can find is here:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.skills') WITH (
        PersonId int './Id',
        SkillTitle nvarchar(50) '$.title'
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code snippet would give you the required results -

```
SELECT
    JSON_Value (c.value, '$.Id') as ID, 
    JSON_Value (p.value, '$.title') as SkillTitle
FROM OPENJSON (@json) as c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.value,'$.skills') as p
```

Have implemented the same by `CROSS APPLY`ing the `JSON` child node with the parent node and using the `JSON_Value()` function.

Comment: Lovely - `CROSS APPLY` - I get it!  Thank you.